# tengo problemas con este ejercici en javacript de condicionales

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

Aquí dejo lo que hice, lo único que no puedo hacer es que, digamos que al seleccionar grupa y fiebre me salga el alerta de posible covid pero si no selecciono ninguno de los dos me salga Diagnostico desconocido, ahí es donde tengo el problema ya que al parecer no esta tomando los nombres que le indique en el if en caso que la persona no seleccione gripa y fiebre, nose si me hice entender pero quiero que al seccionar esas dos me salga posible covid, pero de no ser así que me salga Diagnostico desconocido grax.

```js
function valida() {
  var num1 = document.getElementById("fiebre").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("gripa").value;
  var num1 = document.getElementById("ardor").value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById("espalda").value;

  if ((fiebre == "fiebre") && (gripa == "gripa")) {
    alert('Posible covid');
  } else {
    alert('Diagnostico desconocido');
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="prueba1" name="form1">
  Prueba diagnostica Covid-19 <br>
  Gripa: <input type="checkbox" name="gripa" id="gripa" value="gripa"><br>
  Fiebre: <input type="checkbox" name="fiebre" id="fiebre" value="fiebre"><br>
  Ardor de estomago: <input type="checkbox" name="ardor" id="ardor" value="ardor"><br>
  Dolor de espalda: <input type="checkbox" name="espalda" id="espalda" value="espalda"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Diagnostico" onclick="valida()"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mi sugerencia para validar `inputs` de tipo `check` es que compruebes si están seleccionados o no mediante `true` o `false`, así te ahorras de saber que valor tienen.

Tu validación quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```html
<script>
function valida(){ 
    var gripa = document.getElementById('gripa').checked;
    var fiebre = document.getElementById('fiebre').checked;

    if(gripa=== true && fiebre === true){
        alert("Posible COVID");
    } else{
        alert("Diagnóstico Desconocido");
    }        
} 
</script> 


<form method="get" action="prueba1" name="form1">
    Prueba diagnostica Covid-19 <br>
    Gripa: <input type="checkbox" name="gripa" id="gripa" value="gripa"><br>
    Fiebre: <input type="checkbox" name="fiebre" id="fiebre" value="fiebre"><br>
    Ardor de estomago: <input type="checkbox" name="ardor" id="ardor" value="ardor"><br>
    Dolor de espalda: <input type="checkbox" name="espalda" id="espalda" value="espalda"><br>
    <input type="button" value="Diagnostico" onclick="valida()"><br> 
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano por ese dato !

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió. Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, no olvides marcarla como correcta. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias bro listo 